# equivalent of gfortran's -static-lbgcc, -static-libgfortran in ifort?

Tags: cmake, gfortran, intel-fortran

Are those flags even necessary with ifort? I honestly could not find anything about it

The story is simple, I need to compile with ifort a code that has CMakeLists file for gfortran, with those compiler flags (among others).

After much work I was able to find equivalence of most flags, except for these 3. I think most of my trouble comes from the fact that most people tend to have the opposite trouble (ifort -> gfortran) which pollutes my search results

Comment: Presumably you mean `-static-libgcc` not `-static-lbgcc`? However, have you looked up what they mean in the GCC documentation, and are struggling to understand what they mean and how they translate, or is your difficulty somewhere else?

Comment: yes, i meant -static-libgcc. I am having difficulty knowing how they translate to ifort, if they do at all. I know they link the libraries statically, but i don't know how to do that in ifort, or if it's even necessary to do so.

Comment: Those flags statically link the GCC and GFortran run-time libraries: Intel Fortran doesn't use those libraries so won't need to link them.

Comment: if that's true it's all the confirmation i needed. If you post it as an answer i can mark it as accepted answer